# How to find the diagonal matrix when transformation and conversion matrices are known?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am stuck with finding the diagonal matrix for eigenvalues. 
Given the matrix T = 
\begin{bmatrix}6&-1\\2&3\end{bmatrix} and change of basis matrix C= (whose columns are eigenvectors of T)
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix} 
How can I calculate the diagonal matrix D = C$^{-1}$TC?

Comment: do you know how to invert and multiply $2\times2$ matrices?

Comment: Yes. I inverted C and got \begin{bmatrix}2&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix} , but when I multiply all of it, I still can't get the right answer

Comment: lower left of inverse should have $-1$; how did you get the eigenvectors?

Comment: They were in the assignment

Comment: If you multiply a matrix by an eigenvector, the result should be a multiple of the eigenvector

Comment: It is easy to verify that the columns of $C$ are *not* eigenvectors of $T$.

Comment: Could you give a more deep explanation, please? Basically, I can't understand what's wrong. And it's get even more complicated when you say that they are not eigenvectors, if the assignment tells me so

Comment: Did you type a number wrong ?

Comment: Omg, there was a mistake, let me recompute the lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer before the question was edited: $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    6 & 2 \\
    1 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix}    \begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
8 \\
4 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
but if \begin{pmatrix}
    1  \\
    1  \\
    \end{pmatrix} were an eigenvector then the result would be \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda \\
    \lambda  \\
    \end{pmatrix}.

My answer after the question was edited:

Now that you have the matrix correct, it works:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & -1 \\
    -1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    6 & -1 \\
    2 & 3 \\
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    5 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$
is diagonal.
 The correct inverse is $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 1 \\
    1 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & -1 \\
    \color{red}-1 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I had a mistake in the T matrix. Please, check again.

Comment: What do you get as the answer? When i perform the matrix multiplication, I can't get the right one.

Comment: That's how to invert a $2\times 2$ matrix

Comment: OMG, thank you! I got my mistake.

Comment: you had a couple mistakes (wrong matrix, wrong inverse) but I'm glad the problem is now solved

Comment: Could you tell me what the diagonal matrix actually gives us?

Comment: it's the transformation matrix when the basis is eigenvectors; the diagonal entries are the eigenvalues

Comment: So diagonal matrix scales our eigenvectors and afterwards then we change basis to non-eigen?